# Use of spaces in an acronym with a colon

Tags: acronyms

Is there a space after the colon in an acronym that has a subtitle....should it be COG: S with a space after the colon, or COG:S with not space after the colon?

Comment: Surely an acronym contains no punctuation, because it is [An abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acronym)

Comment: @WeatherVane OP is referring to scenarios like abbreviating Star Trek: Deep Space Nine to ST:DS9, where keeping the separation between the two titles is desirable.

Comment: @eyeballfrog "ST:DS9" is an initialism not an acronym. "COGS" could be an acronym but, as noted, "COG:S" isn't.

Comment: An acronym is a pronounceable word, and words, pronounceable or not, don't have colons in them.